# How to check if a subarray exists in a 2D array in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I'm trying to create a 64 x 64 image dataset for machine learning from a 2D (576 x 768) geographic array.

The array contains *nan* values in random locations (random *i,j*) and the extracted 64 x 64 arrays (images) should not contain any *nan* values. There's also a mask limiting the amount of appropriate arrays.

What I've done for now is generate random pairs of *i* and *j* and examined them for *nan* values and too much overlapping.

What I need help with is figuring out how to check if after *x* extractions there remains a 64 x 64 are that hasn't been sampled too many times.

For illustration purposes, this task is equivalent for locating

```
11
11
```

in

```
000111000
001110000
001111100
011001100
000111100
```

It is crucial that the 2x2 form is not compromised.

Any ideas how to do this efficiently?

Comment: what would be the output here?

Comment: true or false, so I can put this part in a while loop and avoid getting stuck in a forever loop. this is not quite exactly my problem, but a bit broader in hopes of getting a right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to perform a 2d cross-correlation
([Here is the scipy cross-correlation documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.correlate2d.html))

It returns an array with each value being the similitude between the patern and the image at the coordinates of this value. If it's 1, that means the image is exatly the same as the pattern.

Comment: I've attempted it on a small scale example, it doesn't really do a good job at recognizing the same pattern, example: import numpy as np
import scipy.signal as sp
a = np.array([[0,0,0,1,0,0],
             [0,0,2,3,0,0],
             [0,0,0,0,0,0],
             [0,0,0,0,0,0]])

c = np.array([[0,0,1,0,0,0],
             [0,0,2,3,0,0],
             [0,0,0,0,0,0],
             [0,0,0,0,0,0]])



b = np.array([[0,1],
             [2,3]])






corr1 = sp.correlate2d(a, b, mode='same')
corr2 = sp.correlate2d(c, b, mode='same')

Comment: If you divide the output by np.sum(b**2), you get 1 where the pattern is the same